# Cross validation in R vs scikit-learn for linear regression R2

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I have a simple linear regression model as such:

Y = Mean_energy , X = A + B

My dataset consist of only 23 rows.

Therefore, to obtain the training R2 of the model, I did a 5-fold cross validation (cv).

Model used in Python is scikit's LinearRegression and in R is lm.

To do cv in Python, I used cross_validate function in scikit-learn,
 `cross_validate(model, X, Y, cv=5, scoring='r2')`.

To do cv in R, I used the caret package 
`model <- train(Y ~ A + B ,data = df, method = "lm", trControl = train.control)`
`trControl=trainControl(method = "cv", number = 5)`. And then use `model$resample` to check the cv R2.

The cv R2 in R fluctuate a lot compared to Python. See the results below. Any idea why? Thank you.

Note the R2 below are not the test score, it is the training R2 of the model.

Training cv R2 in R:

```
Fold 1 = 0.6686680
Fold 2 = 0.3571826
Fold 3 = 0.8858084
Fold 4 = 0.7081766
Fold 5 = 0.3101449
```

Training cv R2 in Python:

```
Fold 1 = 0.29353287
Fold 2 = 0.24257606
Fold 3 = 0.38664367
Fold 4 = 0.26943862
Fold 5 = 0.24531835
```

FYI, for R cross validation I refer to https://quantdev.ssri.psu.edu/tutorials/cross-validation-tutorial

Dataset: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1rLeJ9_myCboM4jzX0wZ9rSZ3s9aRpLTo/view?usp=sharing

```
Y, A, B
12.48, 0.22, 0.33
5.32, 0.11, 0.22
13.71, 0.33, 0.44
27.48, 0.56, 0.44
3.87, 0.22, 0.56
3.88, 0.33, 0.11
37.90, 0.56, 0.11
10.62, 0.44, 0.22
41.71, 0.44, 0.44
1.96, 0.11, 0.33
25.14, 0.22, 0.33
2.25, 0.33, 0.33
9.73, 0.11, 0.22
8.67, 0.44, 0.33
3.80, 0.56, 0.33
35.90, 0.44, 0.33
3.43, 0.33, 0.11
6.68, 0.11, 0.56
13.54, 0.44, 0.44
8.04, 0.33, 0.22
6.41, 0.56, 0.11
31.67, 0.11, 0.67
70.59, 0.33, 0.56
```

Comment: interesting question. could you post a link to your csv or just hardcode the data to be read into a dataframe so that we can reproduce this?

Comment: @MaxPower i added the csv link

Comment: what is the model of python?

Comment: @PV8 scikit Linear Regression. I will make it clear in the post

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this helps, but the python score is correct:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'Y': [12.48, 5.32, 13.71, 27.48, 3.87, 3.88, 37.90, 10.62, 41.71, 1.96, 25.14, 2.25, 9.73, 8.67, 3.80, 35.90, 3.43, 6.68, 13.54, 8.04, 6.41, 31.67, 70.59],
     'A': [0.22, 0.11,0.33,0.56,0.22, 0.33, 0.56, 0.44, 0.44, 0.11, 0.22, 0.33, 0.11, 0.44, 0.56, 0.44, 0.33, 0.11, 0.44, 0.33, 0.56, 0.11, 0.33],
     'B': [0.33, 0.22, 0.44, 0.44, 0.56, 0.11, 0.11, 0.22, 0.44, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.22, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.11, 0.56, 0.44, 0.22, 0.11, 0.67, 0.56]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
model = LinearRegression()
X = df[['A', 'B']]
Y = df[['Y']]
cross_validate(model, X, Y, cv=5, scoring='r2')
```

Output:

```
{'fit_time': array([0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.01559973]),
 'score_time': array([0.01559997, 0.        , 0.        , 0.        , 0.        ]),
 'test_score': array([-1.31785296,  0.02722109, -4.055718  , -0.07446545, -0.39258268]),
 'train_score': array([0.29353287, 0.24257606, 0.38664367, 0.26943862, 0.24531835])}
```

The output is even worste, if you see the test score.

I have no idea what R is doing, but if you see the [correlation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html): `df.corr()`:

[image]

This is also not good, if you ask me, R is doing some overfitting and you see the train score ?

Comment: Yes i am looking at the training R2 of the model. I am thinking it might be related to the way R2's caret package do the random k-fold splitting. @PV8